# Regexp in url rule

Tags: regex

In `.htaccess` I set the rule, like this:

```
.../([A-zА-я0-9\-\(\)\+\ ]*)/...
```

But it works only for *a-z 0-9 and space*, why didn`t work rule for an url like:

```
/first/broblem (Area)/
```

Comment: learn some regular expression. its good

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the forward slash.

```
.../([A-zА-я0-9\-\(\)\+\ /]*)/...
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression you provided will match sub-expressions

- first
- broblem (Area)

But not the whole line as it does not match the '/' character.

Try this instead:

```
([A-zА-я0-9\-\(\)\+\ \/]*)
```

Not sure how .htaccess files work. Maybe you also need to turn the '*' into a '+' to avoid empty matches... (unless full-line matches are implied)